# Projective representation of stabilizer of induced character

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose $K\trianglelefteq N\trianglelefteq G$ are finite groups and $\rho$ is an irreducible representation of $N$. If $\rho$ is $G$-invariant and irreducible, there is a projective representation $\psi$ of $G$ such that
\begin{equation}\rho(gng^{-1})=\psi(g)\rho(n)\psi(g)^{-1}\end{equation}
for all $n\in N$. I am trying to find a good formula for $\psi$ when $\rho$ is induced from a representation $\varphi$ of $K$. It seems like there should be a nice formula for $\psi$ in terms of $\varphi$ that can be found just using definitions, but I'm getting a bit tripped up.

(A way to find $\psi$ is as follows: define $\psi$ arbitrarily so that the above equation is satisfied on a transversal $T$ of $N$ in $G$; then for $t\in T$ and $n\in N$ define $\psi(tn)=\psi(t)\rho(n)$. )

Any suggestions/hints/answers greatly appreciated! :)

(Also, I can make a few more assumptions if need be.)